# What objects are available for triggers

Tags: trigger

Is there a list or a way to determine what objects are available for triggers?

I'm looking at writing one on `PermissionSetAssignment`.  I looked up the properties on workbench and didn't see anything that resembled `triggerable`, and Googling this was not fruitful. I suppose I could try writing one and see what happens, but that seems rather crude.

[image: permissions set assignment properties in workbench]

Comment: This post has a clever way of sorting out which ones are triggerable https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/172064/10062

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workbench, as you appear to have been using, was the correct tool. The fact that  `permission set` didn't show as triggerable told you what you needed to know. Unfortunately, that's the behavior of how Workbench works. Below, you'll see a screen capture from Workbench looking at User which is triggerable. Workbench only shows the information if an object supports triggers and omits it if it doesn't.

[image: Workbench Screen Capture]

Comment: Thanks I had just made up the word triggerable...didn't realize it existed and would not show up if false.

Answer (score 1):

Apex has a class called Schema. It renders the entire list of objects of your org, including fields, field type etc. The Apex class:

```
<apex:page controller="objectList" >
  <apex:form >
    <apex:SelectList value="{!val}" size="1">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!Name}"></apex:selectOptions> 
    </apex:SelectList>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

The Visualforce page:

```
public class objectList{
  public String val {get;set;}

  public List<SelectOption> getName()
  {
    List<Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values();     
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    for(Schema.SObjectType f : gd)
    {
       options.add(new SelectOption(f.getDescribe().getLabel(),f.getDescribe().getLabel()));
    }
    return options;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Eclipse IDE then there is one way. When you select new ApexTrigger it will give you all available object on which you can create trigger.

Also i am not sure but you can try metadata and Tooling Api may be they will give you option.

Last option is store all Standard object in a Custom Setting in which you can create trigger because you can create trigger on every custom object. but eclipse IDE will come handy in your case.