# Which standard objects don't support triggers?

Tags: apex, trigger, standard-objects

When architecting a solution, I often find myself wanting to know which (of the less-used) standard objects support triggers.

Does anyone know of a single compiled list of standard objects that are **not triggerable**, for quick reference?

The emphasis here is on **quick** reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a quick script to dynamically get a list of all non-triggerable objects on demand.

**Run this from Execute Anonymous in the dev console and check the log's debug outputs to find out which standard objects are not currently triggerable:**

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> standardObjDescs = new List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult>();
for (Schema.SObjectType sobj : gd.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobjDesc = sobj.getDescribe();
    if (!sobjDesc.isCustom()) {
        standardObjDescs.add(sobjDesc);
    }
}

List<String> triggerableList = new List<String>();
List<String> NOTtriggerableList = new List<String>();
for (Schema.DescribeSObjectResult schemaDesc : standardObjDescs) {
    String sobjStruct = JSON.serialize(schemaDesc);
    DescribeSobjectResultJSON sobjProps = (DescribeSobjectResultJSON)JSON.deserialize(sobjStruct, DescribeSobjectResultJSON.class);
    if (sobjProps.triggerable) {
        triggerableList.add(sobjProps.name);
    } else {
        NOTtriggerableList.add(sobjProps.name);
    }
}
NOTtriggerableList.sort();
for (String notTrigble : NOTtriggerableList) {
    System.debug(notTrigble);
}

public class DescribeSobjectResultJSON { 
    public String name {get;set;}
    public Boolean triggerable {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Following  [Standard objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_list.htm) don't support trigger, I have gathered so far as of Spring' 17 release.

- AcceptedEventRelation
- AccountContactRelation
- AccountCleanInfo
- AccountContactRole
- AccountFeed
- AccountHistory
- AccountOwnerSharingRule
- AccountPartner
- AccountShare
- AccountTag
- AccountTeamMember
- AccountTerritoryAssignmentRule
- AccountTerritoryAssignmentRuleItem
- AccountTerritorySharingRule
- ActionLinkGroupTemplate
- ActionLinkTemplate
- ActivityHistory
- AdditionalNumber
- AllowedEmailDomain
- Announcement
- ApexClass
- ApexComponent
- ApexLog
- ApexPage
- ApexTestQueueItem
- ApexTestResult
- ApexTestResultLimits
- ApexTestRunResult
- ApexTestSuite
- ApexTrigger
- AppMenuItem
- Approval
- Article Type__DataCategorySelection
- Article Type__Feed
- AssetFeed
- AssetOwnerSharingRule
- AssetShare
- AssetTag
- AssignedResource
- AssignmentRule
- AsyncApexJob
- AttachedContentDocument
- AttachedContentNote
- AuraDefinition
- AuraDefinitionBundle
- AuthConfig
- AuthConfigProviders
- AuthProvider
- AuthSession
- BackgroundOperation
- BackgroundOperationResult
- Bookmark
- BrandTemplate
- BusinessHours
- BusinessProcess
- CallCenter
- CampaignFeed
- CampaignInfluence
- CampaignInfluenceModel
- CampaignMemberStatus
- CampaignOwnerSharingRule
- CampaignShare
- CampaignTag
- CaseArticle
- CaseContactRole
- CaseFeed
- CaseHistory
- CaseMilestone
- CaseOwnerSharingRule
- CaseShare
- CaseSolution
- CaseStatus
- CaseTag
- CaseTeamMember
- CaseTeamRole
- CaseTeamTemplate
- CaseTeamTemplateMember
- CaseTeamTemplateRecord
- CategoryData
- CategoryNode
- CategoryNodeLocalization
- ChatterActivity
- ChatterAnswersReputationLevel
- ChatterConversation
- ChatterConversationMember
- ChatterMessage
- ClientBrowser
- CollaborationGroupFeed
- CollaborationGroupMemberRequest
- CollaborationGroupRecord
- CollaborationInvitation
- CombinedAttachment
- Community (Zone)
- ConnectedApplication
- ContactCleanInfo
- ContactFeed
- ContactHistory
- ContactOwnerSharingRule
- ContactShare
- ContactTag
- ContentAsset
- ContentDistributionView
- ContentDocumentFeed
- ContentDocumentHistory
- ContentFolder
- ContentFolderItem
- ContentFolderLink
- ContentFolderMember
- ContentHubItem
- ContentHubRepository
- ContentNote
- ContentVersionHistory
- ContentWorkspace
- ContentWorkspaceDoc
- ContractContactRole
- ContractFeed
- ContractHistory
- ContractHistory
- ContractLineItemHistory
- ContractStatus
- ContractTag
- CorsWhitelistEntry
- CronJobDetail
- CronTrigger
- CurrencyType
- CustomBrand
- CustomBrandAsset
- Custom Object__Feed
- CustomPermission
- CustomPermissionDependency
- DandBCompany
- Dashboard
- DashboardComponent
- DashboardComponentFeed
- DashboardFeed
- DashboardTag
- DataAssessmentFieldMetric
- DataAssessmentMetric
- DataAssessmentValueMetric
- DatacloudCompany
- DatacloudContact
- DatacloudDandBCompany
- DatacloudOwnedEntity
- DatacloudPurchaseUsage
- DatacloudSocialHandle
- DatedConversionRate
- DcSocialProfile
- DcSocialProfileHandle
- DeclinedEventRelation
- Division
- DivisionLocalization
- Document
- DocumentAttachmentMap
- DocumentTag
- Domain
- DomainSite
- DuplicateRule
- EmailDomainKey
- EmailMessageRelation
- EmailServicesAddress
- EmailServicesFunction
- EmailStatus
- EmailTemplate
- EmbeddedServiceDetail
- EntitlementFeed
- EntitlementHistory
- EntitlementTemplate
- EntityHistory
- EntityMilestone
- EntitySubscription
- EnvironmentHubMember
- EventFeed
- EventLogFile
- Lightning Error Event Type
- Lightning Interaction Event Type
- Lightning Page View Event Type
- Lightning Performance Event Type
- Login Event Type — LOGIN_STATUS Values
- EventRelation
- EventTag
- EventWhoRelation
- ExternalDataSource
- ExternalDataUserAuth
- FeedAttachment
- FeedLike
- FeedPollChoice
- FeedPollVote
- FeedPost
- FeedRevision
- FeedTrackedChange
- FieldHistoryArchive
- FieldPermissions
- FiscalYearSettings
- FlexQueueItem
- FlowInterview
- FlowInterviewOwnerSharingRule
- FlowInterviewShare
- Folder
- FolderedContentDocument
- ForecastingAdjustment
- ForecastingFact
- ForecastingItem
- ForecastingOwnerAdjustment
- ForecastingQuota
- ForecastingType
- ForecastingUserPreference
- ForecastShare
- Goal
- GoalFeed
- GoalHistory
- GoalLink
- GoalShare
- GoogleDoc
- Group
- GroupMember
- HashtagDefinition
- Holiday
- IdeaReputation
- IdeaReputationLevel
- IdeaTheme
- KnowledgeableUser
- KnowledgeArticle
- KnowledgeArticleVersion
- KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory
- KnowledgeArticleViewStat
- KnowledgeArticleVoteStat
- LeadCleanInfo
- LeadFeed
- LeadHistory
- LeadOwnerSharingRule
- LeadShare
- LeadStatus
- LeadTag
- LimitAllocationPerApp
- LineitemOverride
- LinkedArticleFeed
- LinkedArticleHistory
- ListView
- ListViewChart
- ListViewChartInstance
- LiveAgentSessionHistory
- LiveAgentSessionOwnerSharingRule
- LiveAgentSessionShare
- LiveChatBlockingRule
- LiveChatButton
- LiveChatButtonDeployment
- LiveChatButtonSkill
- LiveChatDeployment
- LiveChatSensitiveDataRule
- LiveChatTranscriptHistory
- LiveChatTranscriptOwnerSharingRule
- LiveChatTranscriptShare
- LiveChatTranscriptSkill
- LiveChatUserConfig
- LiveChatUserConfigProfile
- LiveChatUserConfigUser
- LoginEvent
- LoginGeo
- LoginHistory
- LoginIp
- LookedUpFromActivity
- MacroInstruction
- MailmergeTemplate
- MatchingRule
- MatchingRuleItem
- MetadataPackage
- MetadataPackageVersion
- Metric
- MetricDataLink
- MetricDataLinkHistory
- MetricFeed
- MetricHistory
- MetricsDataFile
- MetricShare
- MilestoneType
- Name
- NamedCredential
- NavigationLinkSet
- NavigationMenuItem
- NavigationMenuItemLocalization
- Network
- NetworkActivityAudit
- NetworkMember
- NetworkMemberGroup
- NetworkModeration
- NetworkPageOverride
- NetworkSelfRegistration
- NewsFeed
- OauthToken
- NoteAndAttachment
- NoteTag
- ObjectPermissions
- ObjectTerritory2AssignmentRule
- ObjectTerritory2AssignmentRuleItem
- ObjectTerritory2Association
- OpenActivity
- OperatingHours
- OperatingHoursFeed
- OperatingHoursHistory
- OpportunityCompetitor
- OpportunityContactRole
- OpportunityFeed
- OpportunityFieldHistory
- OpportunityHistory
- OpportunityLineItemSchedule
- OpportunityOverride
- OpportunityOwnerSharingRule
- OpportunityPartner
- OpportunityShare
- OpportunitySplitType
- OpportunityStage
- OpportunityTag
- OrderFeed
- OrderHistory
- OrderItemFeed
- OrderItemHistory
- OrderOwnerSharingRule
- Organization
- OrgWideEmailAddress
- OwnedContentDocument
- PackageLicense
- PackagePushError
- PackagePushJob
- PackagePushRequest
- PackageSubscriber
- PartnerNetworkConnection
- PartnerNetworkRecordConnection
- PartnerNetworkSyncLog
- PartnerRole
- Period
- PermissionSet
- PermissionSetAssignment
- PermissionSetLicense
- PermissionSetLicenseAssign
- PlatformAction
- PresenceUserConfig
- PresenceUserConfigProfile
- PresenceUserConfigUser
- Pricebook2History
- PricebookEntry
- ProcessDefinition
- ProcessInstance
- ProcessInstanceHistory
- ProcessInstanceStep
- ProcessInstanceNode
- ProcessInstanceWorkitem
- ProcessNode
- Product2Feed
- ProductEntitlementTemplate
- Profile
- ProfileSkillEndorsementFeed
- ProfileSkillEndorsementHistory
- ProfileSkillFeed
- ProfileSkillHistory
- ProfileSkillShare
- ProfileSkillUserFeed
- ProfileSkillUserHistory
- PushTopic
- QuantityForecast
- QuantityForecastHistory
- QueueRoutingConfig
- QuestionDataCategorySelection
- QuestionReportAbuse
- QuestionSubscription
- QueueSobject
- QuickTextHistory
- QuickTextOwnerSharingRule
- QuickTextShare
- QuoteDocument
- QuoteFeed
- RecentlyViewed
- RecordType
- RecordTypeLocalization
- ReplyReportAbuse
- Report
- ReportFeed
- ReportTag
- ReputationLevel
- ReputationLevelLocalization
- ReputationPointsRule
- ResourceAbsence
- ResourceAbsenceFeed
- ResourceAbsenceHistory
- RevenueForecast
- RevenueForecastHistory
- RuleTerritory2Association
- SamlSsoConfig
- Scontrol
- ScontrolLocalization
- SearchPromotionRule
- SecureAgent
- SecureAgentsCluster
- SecurityCustomBaseline (Beta)
- SelfServiceUser
- ServiceAppointment
- ServiceAppointmentFeed
- ServiceAppointmentHistory
- ServiceAppointmentOwnerSharingRule
- ServiceAppointmentShare
- ServiceChannel
- ServiceChannelStatus
- ServiceContractFeed
- ServiceContractHistory
- ServiceContractOwnerSharingRule
- ServiceContractShare
- ServicePresenceStatus
- ServiceResource
- ServiceResourceCapacity
- ServiceResourceCapacityFeed
- ServiceResourceCapacityHistory
- ServiceResourceFeed
- ServiceResourceHistory
- ServiceResourceOwnerSharingRule
- ServiceResourceShare
- ServiceResourceSkill
- ServiceResourceSkillFeed
- ServiceResourceSkillHistory
- ServiceTerritory
- ServiceTerritoryFeed
- ServiceTerritoryHistory
- ServiceTerritoryMember
- ServiceTerritoryMemberFeed
- ServiceTerritoryMemberHistory
- SessionPermSetActivation
- SetupAuditTrail
- SetupEntityAccess
- SignupRequest
- Site
- SiteDomain
- SiteHistory
- Skill
- SkillProfile
- SkillRequirement
- SkillRequirementFeed
- SkillRequirementHistory
- SkillUser
- SlaProcess
- SolutionFeed
- SolutionHistory
- SolutionStatus
- SolutionTag
- SOSDeployment
- SOSSession
- SOSSessionActivity
- SOSSessionHistory
- SOSSessionOwnerSharingRule
- SOSSessionShare
- Stamp
- StampAssignment
- StaticResource
- TagDefinition
- TaskFeed
- TaskPriority
- TaskRelation
- TaskStatus
- TaskTag
- TaskWhoRelation
- TenantSecret
- Territory2Model
- Territory2ModelHistory
- Territory2Type
- TestSuiteMembership
- ThirdPartyAccountLink
- TimeSlot
- TimeSlotHistory
- TopicFeed
- TopicLocalization—Beta
- TwoFactorInfo
- TwoFactorMethodsInfo
- TwoFactorTempCode
- UndecidedEventRelation
- UserAccountTeamMember
- UserAppInfo
- UserAppMenuCustomization
- UserAppMenuCustomizationShare
- UserAppMenuItem
- UserConfigTransferButton
- UserConfigTransferSkill
- UserCustomBadge
- UserCustomBadgeLocalization
- UserFeed
- UserLicense
- UserLogin
- UserMembershipSharingRule
- UserPackageLicense
- UserPreference
- UserProfile
- UserProfileFeed
- UserProvisioningConfig
- UserProvisioningRequestOwnerSharingRule
- UserProvisioningRequestShare
- UserRecordAccess
- UserRole
- UserShare
- UserTeamMember
- UserTerritory
- VerificationHistory
- VoiceCall
- VoiceCallList
- VoiceCallListItem
- VoiceCallListShare
- VoiceCallShare
- VoiceMailContent
- VoiceMailContentShare
- VoiceUserLine
- VoiceUserLineShare
- VoiceVendorInfo
- VoiceVendorLine
- VoiceVendorLineShare
- Vote
- WebLink
- WebLinkLocalization
- WorkAccess
- WorkAccessShare
- WorkBadgeDefinitionHistory
- WorkBadgeDefinitionShare
- WorkCoaching
- WorkCoachingFeed
- WorkCoachingHistory
- WorkCoachingShare
- WorkFeedback
- WorkFeedbackHistory
- WorkFeedbackQuestion
- WorkFeedbackQuestionHistory
- WorkFeedbackQuestionSet
- WorkFeedbackQuestionSetHistory
- WorkFeedbackQuestionSetShare
- WorkFeedbackQuestionShare
- WorkFeedbackRequest
- WorkFeedbackRequestFeed
- WorkFeedbackRequestHistory
- WorkFeedbackRequestShare
- WorkFeedbackShare
- WorkGoal
- WorkGoalCollaborator
- WorkGoalCollaboratorHistory
- WorkGoalFeed
- WorkGoalHistory
- WorkGoalLink
- WorkGoalShare
- WorkOrder
- WorkOrderFeed
- WorkOrderHistory
- WorkOrderLineItem
- WorkOrderLineItemFeed
- WorkOrderLineItemHistory
- WorkOrderShare
- WorkPerformanceCycle
- WorkPerformanceCycleFeed
- WorkPerformanceCycleHistory
- WorkPerformanceCycleShare
- WorkReward
- WorkRewardFund
- WorkRewardFundHistory
- WorkRewardFundShare
- WorkRewardFundType
- WorkRewardFundTypeHistory
- WorkRewardFundTypeShare
- WorkRewardHistory
- WorkRewardShare
- WorkThanksShare
- WorkType
- WorkTypeFeed
- WorkTypeHistory

Comment: I have gathered by manual comparison, if anybody find any mistake then correct me.

Comment: I am impressed! Out of curiosity did you use an API to gather the info?

Comment: taken latest API document and got trigger applicable objects from Developer console and then prepare a excel to compile

Comment: Clever, does anyone know if the metadata or tooling APIs expose the list of possible trigger objects?

Comment: I need to find out, possibly yes, otherwise, how Salesforce could keep track of supported objects

Comment: I would usually think the same thing but they don't API expose super useful things like the list of Pricebooks the current user has access to.

Comment: It might be simpler to list the standard objects that *do* support triggers instead...

Answer (score 2):

Just as latest update, we can now develop trigger on some object given above like WorkOrder and WorkOrderLineItem.

I just developed a good workaround to list such items. Even you can use this code to filter out some other types objects (deleteable, searchable...) as well.

Add your org base URL in a remote site setting and run below given code in dev console:

```
String endpoint = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/sobjects/';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
endpoint += '';
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
req.setMethod('GET');
Http httpreq = new Http();
HttpResponse  res  = httpreq.send(req);
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
List<Object> ob = (List<Object>)m.get('sobjects');
string csv = '';
for(Object o : ob){
    Map<String, Object> real = (Map<String, Object>)o;
    if((Boolean)real.get('triggerable')){
        csv+= real.get('name')+',';
    }
}
system.debug(csv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Enriching the list with additional `Objects`:

```
AcceptedEventRelation
AccountCleanInfo
AccountContactRelation
AccountContactRole
AccountFeed
AccountHistory
AccountOwnerSharingRule
AccountPartner
AccountShare
AccountTag
AccountTeamMember
AccountTerritoryAssignmentRule
AccountTerritoryAssignmentRuleItem
AccountTerritorySharingRule
ActionLinkGroupTemplate
ActionLinkTemplate
ActivityHistory
AdditionalNumber
AgentWorkShare
AggregateResult
AIApplication
AIApplicationConfig
AIInsightAction
AIInsightFeedback
AIInsightReason
AIInsightValue
AllowedEmailDomain
Announcement
ApexClass
ApexComponent
ApexEmailNotification
ApexLog
ApexPage
ApexPageInfo
ApexTestQueueItem
ApexTestResult
ApexTestResultLimits
ApexTestRunResult
ApexTestSuite
ApexTrigger
AppDefinition
AppMenuItem
Approval
AppTabMember
AssetFeed
AssetHistory
AssetOwnerSharingRule
AssetRelationshipFeed
AssetRelationshipHistory
AssetShare
AssetTag
AssignedResource
AssignmentRule
AssociatedLocationHistory
AsyncApexJob
AttachedContentDocument
AttachedContentNote
Audience
AuraDefinition
AuraDefinitionBundle
AuraDefinitionBundleInfo
AuraDefinitionInfo
AuthConfig
AuthConfigProviders
AuthorizationFormConsentHistory
AuthorizationFormConsentShare
AuthorizationFormDataUseHistory
AuthorizationFormDataUseShare
AuthorizationFormHistory
AuthorizationFormShare
AuthorizationFormTextHistory
AuthProvider
AuthSession
BackgroundOperation
BackgroundOperationResult
Bookmark
BrandingSet
BrandingSetProperty
BrandTemplate
BusinessHours
BusinessProcess
Calendar
CalendarView
CalendarViewShare
CallCenter
CallCoachingMediaProvider
CampaignFeed
CampaignHistory
CampaignInfluence
CampaignInfluenceModel
CampaignMemberStatus
CampaignOwnerSharingRule
CampaignShare
CampaignTag
CaseArticle
CaseContactRole
CaseFeed
CaseHistory
CaseMilestone
CaseOwnerSharingRule
CaseShare
CaseSolution
CaseStatus
CaseSubjectParticle
CaseTag
CaseTeamMember
CaseTeamRole
CaseTeamTemplate
CaseTeamTemplateMember
CaseTeamTemplateRecord
CategoryData
CategoryNode
CategoryNodeLocalization
ChatterActivity
ChatterAnswersReputationLevel
ChatterConversation
ChatterConversationMember
ChatterExtension
ChatterExtensionConfig
ChatterMessage
ClientBrowser
CollaborationGroupFeed
CollaborationGroupMemberRequest
CollaborationGroupRecord
CollaborationInvitation
ColorDefinition
CombinedAttachment
CommSubscriptionChannelTypeFeed
CommSubscriptionChannelTypeHistory
CommSubscriptionChannelTypeShare
CommSubscriptionConsentFeed
CommSubscriptionConsentHistory
CommSubscriptionConsentShare
CommSubscriptionFeed
CommSubscriptionHistory
CommSubscriptionShare
CommSubscriptionTimingFeed
CommSubscriptionTimingHistory
Community
Community (Zone)
ConferenceNumber
ConnectedApplication
ContactCleanInfo
ContactFeed
ContactHistory
ContactOwnerSharingRule
ContactPointAddressHistory
ContactPointAddressShare
ContactPointConsentHistory
ContactPointConsentShare
ContactPointEmailHistory
ContactPointEmailShare
ContactPointPhoneHistory
ContactPointPhoneShare
ContactPointTypeConsentHistory
ContactPointTypeConsentShare
ContactRequestShare
ContactShare
ContactTag
ContentAsset
ContentBody
ContentDistributionView
ContentDocumentFeed
ContentDocumentHistory
ContentDocumentSubscription
ContentFolder
ContentFolderItem
ContentFolderLink
ContentFolderMember
ContentHubItem
ContentHubRepository
ContentNote
ContentNotification
ContentTagSubscription
ContentUserSubscription
ContentVersionComment
ContentVersionHistory
ContentVersionRating
ContentWorkspace
ContentWorkspaceDoc
ContentWorkspaceMember
ContentWorkspacePermission
ContentWorkspaceSubscription
ContractContactRole
ContractFeed
ContractHistory
ContractLineItemHistory
ContractStatus
ContractTag
ConversationEntry
CorsWhitelistEntry
CronJobDetail
CronTrigger
CspTrustedSite
CurrencyType
CustomBrand
CustomBrandAsset
CustomHelpMenuItem
CustomHelpMenuSection
CustomHttpHeader
CustomNotificationType
CustomObjectUserLicenseMetrics
CustomPermission
CustomPermissionDependency
CustomSetup
CustomSetupDefinition
DandBCompany
Dashboard
DashboardComponent
DashboardComponentFeed
DashboardFeed
DashboardTag
DataAssessmentFieldMetric
DataAssessmentMetric
DataAssessmentValueMetric
DatacloudAddress
DatacloudCompany
DatacloudContact
DatacloudDandBCompany
DatacloudOwnedEntity
DatacloudPurchaseUsage
DatacloudSocialHandle
DataIntegrationRecordPurchasePermission
DataStatistics
DataType
DataUseLegalBasisHistory
DataUseLegalBasisShare
DataUsePurposeHistory
DataUsePurposeShare
DatedConversionRate
DcSocialProfile
DcSocialProfileHandle
DeclinedEventRelation
DelegatedAccountFeed
DelegatedAccountHistory
DelegatedAccountShare
DeleteEvent
Division
DivisionLocalization
Document
DocumentAttachmentMap
DocumentTag
Domain
DomainSite
DuplicateRule
EmailCapture
EmailDomainKey
EmailMessageRelation
EmailServicesAddress
EmailServicesFunction
EmailStatus
EmailTemplate
EmbeddedServiceDetail
EmbeddedServiceLabel
EngagementChannelTypeFeed
EngagementChannelTypeHistory
EngagementChannelTypeShare
EnhancedLetterhead
EnhancedLetterheadFeed
EntitlementFeed
EntitlementHistory
EntitlementTemplate
EntityDefinition
EntityHistory
EntityMilestone
EntityParticle
EntitySubscription
EnvironmentHubMember
EventBusSubscriber
EventFeed
EventLogFile
EventRelation
EventTag
EventWhoRelation
ExpressionFilter
ExpressionFilterCriteria
ExternalDataSource
ExternalDataUserAuth
ExternalEvent
ExternalEventMapping
ExternalEventMappingShare
ExternalSocialAccount
FeedAttachment
FeedLike
FeedPollChoice
FeedPollVote
FeedPost
FeedRevision
FeedSignal
FeedTrackedChange
FieldDefinition
FieldHistoryArchive
FieldPermissions
FieldSecurityClassification
FileSearchActivity
FiscalYearSettings
FlexQueueItem
FlowDefinitionView
FlowExecutionErrorEvent
FlowInterview
FlowInterviewLog
FlowInterviewLogEntry
FlowInterviewLogShare
FlowInterviewOwnerSharingRule
FlowInterviewShare
FlowRecordRelation
FlowStageRelation
FlowVariableView
FlowVersionView
Folder
FolderedContentDocument
ForecastingAdjustment
ForecastingFact
ForecastingItem
ForecastingOwnerAdjustment
ForecastingQuota
ForecastingType
ForecastingUserPreference
ForecastShare
FormulaFunction
FormulaFunctionAllowedType
FormulaFunctionCategory
Goal
GoalFeed
GoalHistory
GoalLink
GoalShare
GoogleDoc
GrantedByLicense
Group
GroupMember
HashtagDefinition
Holiday
IconDefinition
IdeaReputation
IdeaReputationLevel
IdeaTheme
IdpEventLog
IframeWhiteListUrl
ImageFeed
ImageHistory
ImageShare
IndividualHistory
IndividualShare
InstalledMobileApp
KnowledgeableUser
KnowledgeArticle
KnowledgeArticleVersion
KnowledgeArticleVersionHistory
KnowledgeArticleViewStat
KnowledgeArticleVoteStat
LeadCleanInfo
LeadFeed
LeadHistory
LeadOwnerSharingRule
LeadShare
LeadStatus
LeadTag
Lightning Error Event Type
Lightning Interaction Event Type
Lightning Page View Event Type
Lightning Performance Event Type
LightningExperienceTheme
LightningOnboardingConfig
LimitAllocationPerApp
LineitemOverride
LinkedArticleFeed
LinkedArticleHistory
ListEmail
ListEmailIndividualRecipient
ListEmailRecipientSource
ListEmailShare
ListView
ListViewChart
ListViewChartInstance
LiveAgentSessionHistory
LiveAgentSessionOwnerSharingRule
LiveAgentSessionShare
LiveChatBlockingRule
LiveChatButton
LiveChatButtonDeployment
LiveChatButtonSkill
LiveChatDeployment
LiveChatSensitiveDataRule
LiveChatTranscriptFeed
LiveChatTranscriptHistory
LiveChatTranscriptOwnerSharingRule
LiveChatTranscriptShare
LiveChatTranscriptSkill
LiveChatUserConfig
LiveChatUserConfigProfile
LiveChatUserConfigUser
LocationFeed
LocationHistory
LocationShare
LocationTrustMeasureShare
LoginEvent
LoginGeo
LoginHistory
LoginIp
LookedUpFromActivity
MacroHistory
MacroInstruction
MacroShare
MacroUsageShare
MailmergeTemplate
MatchingInformation
MatchingRule
MatchingRuleItem
MessagingChannel
MessagingChannelSkill
MessagingConfiguration
MessagingEndUserHistory
MessagingEndUserShare
MessagingLink
MessagingSessionFeed
MessagingSessionHistory
MessagingSessionShare
MessagingTemplate
MetadataPackage
MetadataPackageVersion
Metric
MetricDataLink
MetricDataLinkHistory
MetricFeed
MetricHistory
MetricsDataFile
MetricShare
MilestoneType
MLField
MLPredictionDefinition
MobileApplicationDetail
MsgChannelLanguageKeyword
MutingPermissionSet
MyDomainDiscoverableLogin
Name
NamedCredential
NavigationLinkSet
NavigationMenuItem
NavigationMenuItemLocalization
Network
NetworkActivityAudit
NetworkAffinity
NetworkDiscoverableLogin
NetworkFeedResponseMetric
NetworkMember
NetworkMemberGroup
NetworkModeration
NetworkPageOverride
NetworkSelfRegistration
NetworkUserHistoryRecent
NewsFeed
NoteAndAttachment
NoteTag
OauthCustomScope
OauthCustomScopeApp
OauthToken
ObjectPermissions
ObjectTerritory2AssignmentRule
ObjectTerritory2AssignmentRuleItem
ObjectTerritory2Association
OmniRoutingEventStore
OmniSupervisorConfig
OmniSupervisorConfigGroup
OmniSupervisorConfigProfile
OmniSupervisorConfigUser
OnboardingMetrics
OpenActivity
OperatingHours
OperatingHoursFeed
OperatingHoursHistory
OpportunityCompetitor
OpportunityContactRole
OpportunityFeed
OpportunityFieldHistory
OpportunityHistory
OpportunityLineItemSchedule
OpportunityOverride
OpportunityOwnerSharingRule
OpportunityPartner
OpportunityShare
OpportunitySplitType
OpportunityStage
OpportunityTag
OrderFeed
OrderHistory
OrderItemFeed
OrderItemHistory
OrderOwnerSharingRule
OrderShare
OrderStatus
Organization
OrgWideEmailAddress
OutgoingEmail
OutgoingEmailRelation
OwnedContentDocument
OwnerChangeOptionInfo
PackageLicense
PackagePushError
PackagePushJob
PackagePushRequest
PackageSubscriber
PartnerNetworkConnection
PartnerNetworkRecordConnection
PartnerNetworkSyncLog
PartnerRole
PartyConsentFeed
PartyConsentHistory
PartyConsentShare
PendingServiceRoutingShare
Period
PermissionSet
PermissionSetAssignment
PermissionSetGroup
PermissionSetGroupComponent
PermissionSetLicense
PermissionSetLicenseAssign
PermissionSetTabSetting
PersonalizationTargetInfo
PicklistValueInfo
PlatformAction
PlatformCachePartition
PlatformCachePartitionType
PlatformEventUsageMetric
PresenceConfigDeclineReason
PresenceDeclineReason
PresenceUserConfig
PresenceUserConfigProfile
PresenceUserConfigUser
Pricebook2History
PricebookEntry
PricebookEntryHistory
ProcessDefinition
ProcessExceptionShare
ProcessInstance
ProcessInstanceHistory
ProcessInstanceNode
ProcessInstanceStep
ProcessInstanceWorkitem
ProcessNode
Product2Feed
Product2History
ProductEntitlementTemplate
Profile
ProfileSkillEndorsementFeed
ProfileSkillEndorsementHistory
ProfileSkillFeed
ProfileSkillHistory
ProfileSkillShare
ProfileSkillUserFeed
ProfileSkillUserHistory
Prompt
PromptActionShare
PromptVersion
Publisher
PushTopic
QuantityForecast
QuantityForecastHistory
QuestionDataCategorySelection
QuestionReportAbuse
QuestionSubscription
QueueRoutingConfig
QueueSobject
QuickTextHistory
QuickTextOwnerSharingRule
QuickTextShare
QuickTextUsageShare
QuoteDocument
QuoteFeed
QuoteShare
QuoteTemplateRichTextData
RecentlyViewed
RecordActionHistory
RecordType
RecordTypeLocalization
RedirectWhitelistUrl
RelationshipDomain
RelationshipInfo
ReplyReportAbuse
Report
ReportFeed
ReportTag
ReputationLevel
ReputationLevelLocalization
ReputationPointsRule
ResourceAbsence
ResourceAbsenceFeed
ResourceAbsenceHistory
RevenueForecast
RevenueForecastHistory
RuleTerritory2Association
SamlSsoConfig
Scontrol
ScontrolLocalization
SearchLayout
SearchPromotionRule
SecureAgent
SecureAgentsCluster
SecurityCustomBaseline
SecurityCustomBaseline (Beta)
SelfServiceUser
ServiceAppointment
ServiceAppointmentFeed
ServiceAppointmentHistory
ServiceAppointmentOwnerSharingRule
ServiceAppointmentShare
ServiceChannel
ServiceChannelStatus
ServiceChannelStatusField
ServiceContractFeed
ServiceContractHistory
ServiceContractOwnerSharingRule
ServiceContractShare
ServicePresenceStatus
ServiceResource
ServiceResourceCapacity
ServiceResourceCapacityFeed
ServiceResourceCapacityHistory
ServiceResourceFeed
ServiceResourceHistory
ServiceResourceOwnerSharingRule
ServiceResourceShare
ServiceResourceSkill
ServiceResourceSkillFeed
ServiceResourceSkillHistory
ServiceTerritory
ServiceTerritoryFeed
ServiceTerritoryHistory
ServiceTerritoryMember
ServiceTerritoryMemberFeed
ServiceTerritoryMemberHistory
SessionPermSetActivation
SetupAuditTrail
SetupEntityAccess
SignupRequest
Site
SiteDetail
SiteDomain
SiteFeed
SiteHistory
SiteIframeWhiteListUrl
Skill
SkillProfile
SkillRequirement
SkillRequirementFeed
SkillRequirementHistory
SkillUser
SlaProcess
SocialPersonaHistory
SocialPostFeed
SocialPostHistory
SocialPostShare
SolutionFeed
SolutionHistory
SolutionStatus
SolutionTag
SOSDeployment
SOSSession
SOSSessionActivity
SOSSessionHistory
SOSSessionOwnerSharingRule
SOSSessionShare
Stamp
StampAssignment
StaticResource
StreamingChannelShare
SupervisorAgentConfigSkill
TabDefinition
TagDefinition
TaskFeed
TaskPriority
TaskRelation
TaskStatus
TaskTag
TaskWhoRelation
TenantSecret
TenantUsageEntitlement
Territory2Model
Territory2ModelHistory
Territory2Type
TestSuiteMembership
ThirdPartyAccountLink
TimeSlot
TimeSlotHistory
TodayGoal
TodayGoalShare
TopicFeed
TopicLocalization—Beta
TopicUserEvent
Translation
TwoFactorInfo
TwoFactorMethodsInfo
TwoFactorTempCode
UiFormulaCriterion
UiFormulaRule
UndecidedEventRelation
UserAccountTeamMember
UserAppInfo
UserAppMenuCustomization
UserAppMenuCustomizationShare
UserAppMenuItem
UserConfigTransferButton
UserConfigTransferSkill
UserCustomBadge
UserCustomBadgeLocalization
UserEmailPreferredPerson
UserEmailPreferredPersonShare
UserEntityAccess
UserFeed
UserFieldAccess
UserLicense
UserListView
UserListViewCriterion
UserLogin
UserMembershipSharingRule
UserPackageLicense
UserPermissionAccess
UserPreference
UserProfile
UserProfileFeed
UserProvisioningConfig
UserProvisioningRequestOwnerSharingRule
UserProvisioningRequestShare
UserRecordAccess
UserRole
UserServicePresenceShare
UserSetupEntityAccess
UserShare
UserTeamMember
UserTerritory
VerificationHistory
VisualforceAccessMetrics
VoiceCall
VoiceCallList
VoiceCallListItem
VoiceCallListShare
VoiceCallShare
VoiceMailContent
VoiceMailContentShare
VoiceUserLine
VoiceUserLineShare
VoiceVendorInfo
VoiceVendorLine
VoiceVendorLineShare
Vote
WaveAutoInstallRequest
WaveCompatibilityCheckItem
WebLink
WebLinkLocalization
WorkAccess
WorkAccessShare
WorkBadgeDefinitionHistory
WorkBadgeDefinitionShare
WorkCoaching
WorkCoachingFeed
WorkCoachingHistory
WorkCoachingShare
WorkFeedback
WorkFeedbackHistory
WorkFeedbackQuestion
WorkFeedbackQuestionHistory
WorkFeedbackQuestionSet
WorkFeedbackQuestionSetHistory
WorkFeedbackQuestionSetShare
WorkFeedbackQuestionShare
WorkFeedbackRequest
WorkFeedbackRequestFeed
WorkFeedbackRequestHistory
WorkFeedbackRequestShare
WorkFeedbackShare
WorkGoal
WorkGoalCollaborator
WorkGoalCollaboratorHistory
WorkGoalFeed
WorkGoalHistory
WorkGoalLink
WorkGoalShare
WorkOrder
WorkOrderFeed
WorkOrderHistory
WorkOrderLineItem
WorkOrderLineItemFeed
WorkOrderLineItemHistory
WorkOrderShare
WorkPerformanceCycle
WorkPerformanceCycleFeed
WorkPerformanceCycleHistory
WorkPerformanceCycleShare
WorkReward
WorkRewardFund
WorkRewardFundHistory
WorkRewardFundShare
WorkRewardFundType
WorkRewardFundTypeHistory
WorkRewardFundTypeShare
WorkRewardHistory
WorkRewardShare
WorkThanksShare
WorkType
WorkTypeFeed
WorkTypeHistory
```