# Is there any way to identify which standard object supports trigger and which not?

Tags: trigger

Some standard object does not support trigger. So when I start writing trigger and then it gives error. Is there any proper way/ documentation which I can refer to decide whether any salesforce standard object supports trigger or not?

I know we can rely on Developer Console where before writing trigger we need to select salesforce object, but I am looking for some kind of documentation which clearly gives idea about whether trigger can be written or not.
[image]

Comment: you should check https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171844/which-standard-objects-dont-support-triggers

Comment: @glls Thank you for point to right direction. Yes, it is very simple, if I go to workbench and select object and then in objects attribute there is one attribute as triggerable which gives idea about whether we can write tigger or not. Thanks