# Copying EventLogFiles to Custom Object using Process Builder / Flow

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, eventlogfile

I am looking at saving EventLogFile entries to a custom object. In particular I am interested in the ReportExport EventType.

Is it possible to use configuration (not a trigger) to create a record, which populates the EventLogFile details when the event occurs?

I've had a look at process builder, which doesn't seem to have the EventLogFile as an object, am I missing something?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

You cant run a trigger against EventLogFile. See list of SObjects not supported [**here**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171844/which-standard-objects-dont-support-triggers/171846)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally when you create Log file, it should be done in Asynchronous mode, so that System will not wait for Event Log to be generated.

So, using process or flow doesn't support asynchronous operation.

You can use trigger to store values.

Comment: Thanks Santanu. Quick follow up question, can the trigger simply call a flow, pass variables to and create the record? Or is it the same issue?

Comment: I didn't check on Asynchronously calling part of flow, but easy to pass variable from apex to flow.