# What are the objects (or) Account forecast objects does not support Triggers in Manufacturing Cloud?

Tags: apex, trigger, object, cloud

I came across this question which was asked in the 'Manufacturing Cloud' Certification.

Answer (score 0):

For finding out the Non-Triggerable object list, execute the following code snippet in the anonymous window and get the logs.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult> standardObjDescs = new List<Schema.DescribeSObjectResult>();
for (Schema.SObjectType sobj : gd.values()) {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobjDesc = sobj.getDescribe();
    if (!sobjDesc.isCustom()) {
        standardObjDescs.add(sobjDesc);
    }
}

List<String> triggerableList = new List<String>();
List<String> NOTtriggerableList = new List<String>();
for (Schema.DescribeSObjectResult schemaDesc : standardObjDescs) {
    String sobjStruct = JSON.serialize(schemaDesc);
    DescribeSobjectResultJSON sobjProps = (DescribeSobjectResultJSON)JSON.deserialize(sobjStruct, DescribeSobjectResultJSON.class);
    if (sobjProps.triggerable) {
        triggerableList.add(sobjProps.name);
    } else {
        NOTtriggerableList.add(sobjProps.name);
    }
}
NOTtriggerableList.sort();
for (String notTrigble : NOTtriggerableList) {
    System.debug(notTrigble);
}

public class DescribeSobjectResultJSON { 
    public String name {get;set;}
    public Boolean triggerable {get;set;}
}
```

Here are the major Advanced account forecast Objects, that do not support Triggers.
Check the objects which start with '**Adv**'.

[image]

Note: Have referenced the code snippet from the following link, and here sharing the account forecast-level objects only.

For the Code snippets, Credits will go to the actual owner.

[Which standard objects don't support triggers?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171844/which-standard-objects-dont-support-triggers)